# Application Battery Consumption Tool

Tags: android, iphone, ios, performance-testing, battery

Is there a tool that would allow you to measure the battery used in milli amps or milli watts by your application on an iPhone or an Android.  Specifically, I want to run my application with a few test cases, then be able to see how much more battery was used by me running the application versus the phone sitting idle.  I was able to find a tool for Android [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-monitoring-tool-for-android-devices-a-power-and-performance-related-data#features) from Intel, however, it does not offer a similar solution for IOS.  Preferably, I would like to use the same tool for both IOS and Android..

Answer (score 0):

PowerTutor is an application for Google phones that displays the power consumed by major system components such as CPU, network interface, display, and GPS receiver and different applications. The application allows software developers to see the impact of design changes on power efficiency. Application users can also use it to determine how their actions are impacting battery life. PowerTutor uses a power consumption model built by direct measurements during careful control of device power management states. This model generally provides power consumption estimates within 5% of actual values. A configurable display for power consumption history is provided. It also provides users with a text-file based output containing detailed results. You can use PowerTutor to monitor the power consumption of any application.

http://ziyang.eecs.umich.edu/projects/powertutor/

Comment: Thanks for the link... However, I am still looking for a solution that will work for both android and iOS devices.